# Adding new elements to an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a button that when clicked, calls a function that adds (appends) a new element to an array, and the element then gets printed out onto the screen. In this case, I am trying to add new words to an already existing list of words. I'm having several problems:

1. How to get the array to print out on a page like this: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfk2V.jpg). Do I just write several new paragraph tags with line breaks to have the elements of the array show up?
2. There seems to be something fundamentally wrong with my button. It not only doesn't do what I want it to do, but it won't even display the "Try it!" text that I want it to.
3. The addToArray function won't execute when it's called. Whether it's in the wrong place or the function I wrote just is completely wrong syntactically, I have no clue.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<h1>Adding elements onto the end of an array:</h1>
<p>Click the button below to append more values to the array!</p>
<button id="btnAdd" value="Try it!" onclick="addFruitOnClick()"/>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    var foods = [];
    foods[0] = "Banana";
    foods[1] = "Orange";
    foods[2] = "Apple";
    foods[3] = "Mango";
    foods[4] = "Lemon"; 

    var i = 0;
    while (i < foods.length) {
        document.write(foods[i] + "<br />");
    }

function addFruitOnClick() { // Define first function
    document.write("hi");
}

function addToArray() {  // Define what the second function's task is

        foods.concat([ // Using (array.concat) to append to existing array
                    "dragonfruit",
                    "Cherry",
                    "Lime",
                    "Strawberry"
                    ]);
    }

} // End of addToArray
addtoArray ();

</script>
```

I left out my head/body/html tags but that's the jist of it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, addtoArray() is not the same as addToArray()   Also, to add to an array you can just do a push to add to an array.  For example, foods.push("theNextFruit")  Your question makes me think you are doing a homework assignment.  And the fact that the fruit list is the same as the one in w3school https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp  Haha.

Comment: Your while loop is going to run forever.

Comment: @Vbudo Yes this is for homework haha. And thank you for that link that actually helped a lot :)

Comment: @torazaburo any tips of how to make it not run on forever?

Comment: You need to put either i = i +1;  or  i++;  at the end of your while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `push` to add a new element to an array, for example:

```
foods.push("Kiwi");
```

Comment: Thank you to all who've answered it helped a bunch. This is what I ended up with and it works. I was wondering how to write the code so that the button click just prints out one new element from the fruits.push per button click. Also I just want to print the fruits with line breaks so it looks more neat. Any ideas? https://jsfiddle.net/eichtower15/xuou9tdn/

Answer (score 0):

I did some modifications of your code for concat and addFruitOnClick function.

```
var foods = [];
foods[0] = "Banana";
foods[1] = "Orange";
foods[2] = "Apple";
foods[3] = "Mango";
foods[4] = "Lemon"; 

function display(){
     var i = 0;
     while (i < foods.length) {
         document.write(foods[i++] + "<br />");
     }
     document.write("<br />");
}

function addFruitOnClick(fruit) { // Define first function
     foods.push(fruit);
}

function addToArray() {  // Define what the second function's task is

       foods = foods.concat([ // Using (array.concat) to append to existin array
                "dragonfruit",
                "Cherry",
                "Lime",
                "Strawberry"
                ]);

} // End of addToArray

display();
addFruitOnClick("Cherry");
display();
addToArray ();
display();
```

Answer (score 0):

I slightly changed your code - you can play with the concept to mould it to your needs - basically there is a single array of fruits and this is shown as dynamically created list.

I then have a series of buttons that call a function to add a specific food to the array.

Clicking an ad button - allows a new fruit to be added to the array and then all you have to do is re-render the lest to show the new content. This could be amended to remove fruits as well:

```js
var foods = ["Banana", "Orange","Apple", "Mango","Lemon"]

showFoods();

function showFoods() {
  var str= '';
  
  foods.forEach(function(food) {
    str += '<li>' + food + '</li>';
   });
   
  document.getElementById('foods').innerHTML = str;
 }

function addFood(food){
  foods.push(food);
  showFoods();  
}
```

```css
#foods{list-style:none}
```

```html
<ul id="foods"></ul>
<button type="button" onclick="addFood('Dragonfruit')">Add Dragonfruit</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addFood('Cherry')">Add Cherry</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addFood('Lime')">Add Lime</button>
<button type="button" onclick="addFood('Strawberry')">Add Strawberry</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, at the end of your script, you should call `addToArray()`, not `addtoArray()` (case matters)

Next, the function `concat` does not update your array in place, you should write

```
foods = foods.concat([ "dragonfruit", "Cherry" /* ... */ ])
```

or

```
[ "dragonfruit", "Cherry" /* ... */ ].forEach(function(fruit){ food.push(fruit) })
```

Then your code won't run forever anymore.